# why is my code giving NZEC(Runtime error)

Tags: java, runtime-error

My code is running fine on my system but giving NZEC on online system

```
static String fun (String str,int n) throws Exception
{
    String concat="";

    if(n==0)
        return str;
    else
    {
        concat=str+rev(str);
        return fun(concat,(n-1));
    }

}
```

function-2

```
static String rev(String str) throws Exception
{   
    StringBuffer br=new StringBuffer(str);
    br.reverse();
    String revstr=br.toString();
    return revstr;

}
```

function-main

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int test=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for(int p=0;p<test;p++)
        {
            String sub="";
            int count=0;
            String[] line=br.readLine().split(" ");
            String finalstr=fun(line[0],Integer.parseInt(line[1]));
            int length=finalstr.length();

            for( int c = 0 ; c < length ; c++ )
            {
                for( int i = 1 ; i <= length - c ; i++ )
                {
                    sub = finalstr.substring(c, c+i);
                    int subcheck=Integer.parseInt(sub)%1000000007;

                    if(subcheck%3==0)
                    {
                        count++;

                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Just google for the Java challenge you try to solve and "NZEC", then read one of the many findings.

Comment: What means: "NZEC on online system" ????

Comment: @elefasGR its a challenge question ....am submitting the code online, but its giving me NZEC, i just want to know the main reason behind it.

Comment: @Tom i did ...but no satisfactory result

Comment: Ok found it, "NZEC" means "non-zero exit code" in order to help others understand what it means

Comment: Then read the second or third one. Every challenge of the usual hackerrank, hackerearth or codechef sites have already been discussed many times, so keep doing research.

Comment: May I ask why your `main` method throws `IOException` but all your code in the main method is surrounded by a `try catch(Exception e)` clause? Try to clear out your code by removing either the `try catch` or the `throws IOException`

Comment: @elefasGR did but no luck, its working fine on my system but giving NZEC there on the challenge site.

Comment: @shadowclone you mean you submit your code to this url here: https://www.codechef.com/ide   ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on Hackerearth: see: https://code.hackerearth.com/c4cfd4e?key=dd429a7c1e29beb803f5efe4fcd7ec37

its working

I dont know about your inputs .. but I think you will have issue when parsing very big number to Integer in this line:

```
            int subcheck=Integer.parseInt(sub)%1000000007;
```

I added catch NumberFormatException to see more details ..